# If statement based on percentage usage of certain CPU cores

Tags: python, psutil

Python 3.10

Let's say I have a python script like this:

```
import psutil

print("="*40, "CPU Info", "="*40)
print("Physical cores:", psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
print("Total cores:", psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))
print("CPU Usage Per Core:")
for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
    print(f"Core {i}: {percentage}%")
print(f"Total CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%")
```

Which gives the following output:

```
======================================== CPU Info ========================================
Physical cores: 4
Total cores: 8
CPU Usage Per Core:
Core 0: 13.6%
Core 1: 1.5%
Core 2: 18.5%
Core 3: 0.0%
Core 4: 16.9%
Core 5: 7.7%
Core 6: 9.2%
Core 7: 9.2%
Total CPU Usage: 9.7%
```

What I need to be able to add to this is, if any of cores 0 through 3 are above 50% usage, then do something (I know how to write the do something part of the code).

How would I write the if part of this?  Where I'm stuck is indicating the core numbers explicitly.

I will also be required to do this with other cores, and sometimes all of them, but if I see the syntax for my above example, I should be able to figure out how to cover other examples.

Comment: `if percentage >= 50.0:`?

Comment: You have the core number in `i` and you use an `if` block to execute logic. What are you stuck on?

Comment: I am interested only on cores 0-3 explicitly.  I don't see how the above logic captures that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the for loop you should write

```
if percentage > 50 and i < 4:
    #DO
```

Comment: I am interested only on cores 0-3 explicitly.  Your code doesn't seem to consider this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to consider that.

Comment: Ah ok, so you can literally call the enum number of `i` like that.  Ok, that should be simple enough...

Comment: i (standing for index) is simply a number, an integer if that's familiar from strongly-typed languages to you. You can access and use it just as simply as any other variables / numbers

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.  Thanks for your help!